# Clang AST Matcher: No CXXMethodDecl for `operator()`?

Tags: clang, clang-ast-matchers

I have the following `struct` definition in a file:

```
template <class... EventArgs>
struct banana {
    template <class... Args>
    void operator()(Args&&... args) const {
        _f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

private:
    std::function<void(EventArgs...)> _f;
};
```

Using `-ast-dump -fsyntax-only`, I can clearly see multiple `CXXRecordDecl`s in the dump that refer to `banana`, as well as `CXXMethodDecl`s that refer to `operator()`:

```
`-ClassTemplateDecl 0x7fb23c11e028 <./test_files/templates.cpp:12:1, line:21:1> line:13:8 banana
  |-TemplateTypeParmDecl 0x7fb23c11df08 <line:12:11, col:20> col:20 referenced class depth 0 index 0 ... EventArgs
  |-CXXRecordDecl 0x7fb23c11df90 <line:13:1, line:21:1> line:13:8 struct banana definition
  | |-CXXRecordDecl 0x7fb23c11e300 <line:13:1, col:8> col:8 implicit struct banana
  | |-FunctionTemplateDecl 0x7fb23c11e668 <line:14:5, line:17:5> line:15:10 operator()
  | | |-TemplateTypeParmDecl 0x7fb23c11e398 <line:14:15, col:24> col:24 referenced class depth 1 index 0 ... Args
  | | `-CXXMethodDecl 0x7fb23c11e5d0 <line:15:5, line:17:5> line:15:10 operator() 'void (Args &&...) const'
  | | etc., etc.
```

My `MatchFinder::MatchCallback` subclass is being run over the `CXXRecordDecl` for event, however `methods()` is coming back with an empty range:

```
void ClassInfo::run(const MatchFinder::MatchResult& Result) {
    auto clas = Result.Nodes.getNodeAs<clang::CXXRecordDecl>("class");

    for (const auto& method : clas->methods()) {
        // Not getting run - methods() is empty?
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `clas->methods()` only returns `CXXMethodDecl`s in the top level of the `struct`.
But in your `struct`, there is only `FunctionTemplateDecl`.
So, you may wanna do something like this:

```
for (const auto &decl : clas->decls()) {
  if (auto *templ = dyn_cast<FunctionTemplateDecl>(&decl)) {
    // Use templ->getTemplatedDecl to get FunctionDecl.
  }
}
```

**Note.** I haven't actually tested nor compiled that code, but hopefully, you get the idea from it.